# Analog latency in an opamp circuit

Tags: led, operational-amplifier, audio, latency

Say we have 2 audio lines, one is driving an LED via an opamp circuit, and one is driving a speaker. Feeding the same pulse signal to both, are we able to detect latency between the time it takes for the speaker to engage and the LED to emit? 
Thanks in advance

cheers

Comment: This question is unclear. How much latency do you care about? What's the op amp circuit? What kind of speaker is it?

Comment: With what are we doing the detecting? A human? An oscilloscope? What is adding the latency? This is extremely broad, you need to add a *lot* of clarification.

Comment: Are you asking out of idle curiosity, or is there some reason why you want to know this? Any latencies in the audio signals while they are traveling through circuits and wires would normally be very small, and not detectable via normal human senses.

Comment: Plus 1. This is a valid question and shouldn't be closed just because a few people  don't understand what's being asked.

Comment: You'll always see the flash before the bullet hits you. Ditto with lightning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can easily be done, but the target criterion must first be specified.

For example, if the target criterion is the difference in time it takes for current in the loads to rise to 1 milliampere from the time the leading edge of the pulse first hits the loads, then that difference is the latency of which you speak.

In the graphic below, the incident pulse is shown in black, the LED response in red, and the speaker response in green.

The figures are imaginary, but serve to illustrate the concept.

[image]